# Mono.subscribeOn() and error handler behavior

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, project-reactor, azure-sdk-for-java

We have the following web handler which queries some data, process them and update them back into db in the background of the web service with `Mono.subscribeOn()`.

```java
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return request
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .doOnNext(param -> queryData(param) // Query gets a flux of items
                        .collectList() // Data processing require a view of all the data queried, so we need to collect them
                        .flatMapMany(this::executeBulkOperations)
                        .reduce(true, (a, c) -> a && c)  // In case of some update failed, we still want to update the rest (hence not using Flux.any)
                        .flatMap(this::notify)
                        .onErrorResume(e -> {
                            log.error("onErrorResume ", e);
                            return notify(false);
                        })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .doOnError(e -> log.error("doOnError ", e))
                        .subscribe())
                .flatMap(param -> ok().body(Mono.just("ok"), String.class));
    }
```

Note that:

1. We put the query-processing-update under `doOnNext` because the application we are implementing is using best-effort 'fire-and-forget' pattern. When this API is triggered, query-processing-update will take time in the background but the triggering application does not need to wait for its result and even if the server is shutdown in the middle, it is still fine.
2. Everything in the handler is async / reactive but we still put it on `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` because IntelliJ recommended it and I believe if not publisher may get scheduled on epoll / http threads and too many of those stuff can lead to delay in event loops even if it's fully async / reactive.

Our issue happens that sometimes when an error is thrown from `executeBulkOperations`, we observed that `doOnError` is executed but `onErrorResume` is not.

The exact `executeBulkOperations` is an API from [AzureSDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/fc8e083a383c5e25bd03eedc83315067647e0580/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/CosmosAsyncContainer.java#L1251). I tried a couple of things on my end but couldn't seem to implement a function to reproduce the exact error handling behavior (in my cases, `onErrorResume` is always run):

```java
    private Flux<String> queryData(String param) {
        return Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
    }
    private Flux<Boolean> executeBulkOperations(List<String> items) {
        return Flux
                .fromIterable(items)
                .flatMap(c -> c.equals("c") ?
                        Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Boom")) : Mono.just(true)
                );
    }
    private Mono<Boolean> notify(boolean res) {
        return Mono.just(true);
    }
```

While I'm not interested in digging into Microsoft/Azure specific stuff, I'd like to understand:

1. If it's possible to implement a small `executeBulkOperations` which can have the same behavior or perhaps what we observed is rather an abnormal behavior
2. If the above is a normal behavior, what's the best practice for running stuff in the background while also handling error? (perhaps we shouldn't run those background stuff on `boundedElastic()`?)

Comment: reactive streams dont throw exceptions they either return a Mono.just, or a Mono.error its very hard to understand what is happening when we dont have the full picture what is `processDataFromDbWhichMayThrowException` as said before, reactive streams dont throw exceptions. The scheduler has nothing to do with your problem, all that it is saying is that you are running a non-reactive flow. You have basically removed the entire "reactivity" of the flow with that scheduler, the entire flow is now single threaded. Its very rare to return Mono<Boolean> as you usually return a value or an error.

Comment: Mono<Boolean> is just there to make it easier to phrase the question. But you have a point, let me try to dig into AzureSDK further about the exception and see if I am able to create a minimum function to replicate the same behavior

Comment: Also we don’t mix reactive and nonreactive flow. There is no blocking call. We use subscribe because we want this to run in the background rather than holding up the request. Let me update the question for that too.

Comment: That scheduler makes it so that any subscriber will get a single thread that sticks through it during execution, it is supposed to be used as a fallback to make a reactive service be able to use for instance blocking calls och blocking database drivers. Im 99% sure that you should remove it. And i have no idea what you mean by ”holding up the request” the purpose of the scheduler you have chosen is explained here half way down the section https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers

Comment: ”A bounded elastic thread pool (Schedulers.boundedElastic()). This is a handy way to give a blocking process its own thread so that it does not tie up other resources. This is a better choice for I/O blocking work. …, but doesn’t pressure the system too much with new threads. ” im talking about the `Scheduler` and not the `Subscribe`